# Debounce search filter

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to debounce my search function but I get an error.
I have an ember search input and this in my array controller:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    watchSearch: function() {
      Em.run.debounce(this, this.itemsa, 400);
    }.observes("search"),

    itemsa: function() {
      var searched = this.get("search") ? this.get("searchedItems") : this;
      return searched;    
    }.property("searchedItems"),

  searchedItems: function() {
    var search = this.get('search').toLowerCase();
    return this.filter(function(item) {
      return item.get('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1;
    })
  }.property('search', 'title')
});
```

And in my template I have:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
  {{#each itemsa}}
    {{title}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debounce should call a function, not a computed property.

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    watchSearch: function() {
      Em.run.debounce(this, this.runSearch, 400);
    }.observes("search"),

    runSearch: function(){
      this.set('nextSearch', this.get('search'));
    },

    itemsa: function() {
      var searched = this.get("search") ? this.get("searchedItems") : this;
      return searched;    
    }.property("searchedItems"),

  searchedItems: function() {
    var search = this.get('search').toLowerCase();
    return this.filter(function(item) {
      return item.get('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1;
    })
  }.property('nextSearch', 'title')
});
```

#### Examples

- Without debounce: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nigoxaqe/1/edit
- With debounce: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/roqigipo/1/edit

Comment: Right. I feel it should be able to call a computed property. Seems weird to make that extra step.
Thanks. You are so fast @Kingpin2k !

Comment: Yeah, the computed properties give the false sense that they are still functions that can be called, but really they are a different paradigm at that point, they can only be gotten `this.get('itemsa')` which are cacheable and observable etc, but just calling it won't actually make sense in the real world.  And to be honest, we got lucky, I wrote both of those examples last month at an ember meetup http://www.meetup.com/EmberJS-SLC/events/191610842/